# Why use absolute values in Coulombs law?

Tags: electromagnetism, coulombs-law

Coulombs law $F=K_e\frac{|q_1||q_2|}{r^2}$

This gives no indication of the direction of the force should you not have the absolute value in this equation

$(-)*(+)=-$

$(-)*(-)=+$

$(+)*(+)=+$

Thus ignoring the absolute value signs will automatically indicate that if the result is ***negative*** the force is attractive and if ***positive*** is repulsive

Adding absolute values to the equation leaves the user to figure out the direction manually

Comment: You are totally correct and there are no absolute values, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb's_law

Comment: @Noiralef Not so fast.   The notation implies that the expression is for the magnitude of the force, which is always positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forces are vector quantities and therefore have magnitude (or modulus or length) and direction (with sign).

The expression $$ F=k_e{|q_1q_2|\over r^2}$$ is only the magnitude of the force.

The expression written explicitly in vector notation is $$ \mathbf F_1=k_e\frac{q_1q_2}{{|\mathbf r_{12}|}^2} \mathbf{\hat{r}}_{21}$$
where $ \mathbf{{r}}_{21} $ is the vectorial distance between the charges and $\mathbf{\hat{r}}_{21} =\mathbf{{r}}_{21}/|\mathbf{{r}}_{21}| $.

If the system is only one dimensional, then you can trivially consider the vectorial nature of the force formally by just removing the absolute values to the charges as you suggest.

Comment: You need to define what your subscripts mean, as different authors use different definitions.  Mine, which is fairly common:  ${\bf F}_{12}$ is the force on 1 due to 2 and ${\bf r}_{12} = {\bf r}_1 - {\bf r}_2$  One advantage is that the subscripts go in the same order everywhere:  ${\bf F}_{12} \propto \hat{{\bf r}}_{12}/|{\bf r}_{12}|^2 $

Comment: @garyp: you are right, I used a sloppy notation